# The cypher regex operator in neo4j is giving unexpected behavior

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I populated an empty NEO4J store with a single node:

```
 create (P: Per {Name: "Shalom"});
```

queried for it

```
neo4j> match (n) return n;
| (:Per {Name: "Shalom"}) |
```

tried regex, got the strangest response:

```
neo4j> match (n : Per) where n.Name =- ".*lom" return n;
Type mismatch: expected Float or Integer but was String (line 2, column 33 (offset: 33))
"match (n : Per) where n.Name =- ".*lom" return n;"
```

Any idea as to what is wrong here?
Thanks,

Shalom Elkin

Answer (score 2):

The regex operator is not `=-` (equal minus) but `=~` (equal tild).

So your query is : `match (n : Per) where n.Name =~ ".*lom" return n`